# How does this FSP seperate both USER paths?

Tags: state-machine

```
RESOURCE = (acquire->continue->RESOURCE).
USER = (acquire->use->continue->USER).
||RESOURCE_SHARE = (a:USER || b:USER || {a,b}::RESOURCE).
```

[image]

How does the shared action `continue` between `a.USER` and `a.RESOURCE` ensure that the `a.USER` path does not intertwine with the `b.USER` path? For instance, I the LTSA does not allow the following trace, and I don't understand why not.

```
a.acquire->b.acquire->a.use->b.use->...
```

This confusion follows up from comparing it with the following FSP/LTSA. Remove the `continue` action in both processes and we are left with:

```
RESOURCE = (acquire->RESOURCE).
USER = (acquire->use->USER).
||RESOURCE_SHARE = (a:USER || b:USER || {a,b}::RESOURCE).
```

[image]

This FSP/LTSA suddenly DOES allow for the `USER` paths to become intertwined, since we can perform the following trace:

```
a.acquire->b.acquire->a.use->b.use->...
```

Apparently adding continue forces the `USER` paths to go separate ways. Why though?

**Source:**
The first FSP is from the book 'Concurrency' by Jeff Magee and Jeff Kramer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent a mail to my teacher to help me out. I'll paraphrase him:

> There are three processes, two prefixes a and b of USER and
>   {a,b}::RESOURCE. The action 'acquire' from a.USER and b.USER *merges*
>   with {a,b}.acquire from {a,b}::RESOURCE. This also happens for
>   {a,b}.continue.
>
> Therefore, in the first state there are two possible traces enabled: a.acquire OR b.acquire. Assume the action a.acquire is chosen. A transition occurs
>   and a.USER will only have the action a.use enabled, while
>   {a,b}::RESOURCE has two options enabled: {a,b}.continue.
>
> Since a.continue is not yet enabled in a.USER, a.continue cannot occur
>   in {a,b}::RESOURCE. The only action left is for a.use to occur. In the
>   meantime, b.USER is still in the first state, and cannot run b.acquire
>   since {a,b}::RESOURCE only has {a,b}.continue enabled.
>
> After the a.use transition, a.USER is now ready for the shared action
>   a.continue. Once this happens, all three processes are back to the
>   beginning state.